# Number of ordered pairs (a,b) of this equality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

To find the number of ordered pairs (a,b) for which the equality $a(\cos x-1)+b^2=cos(ax+b^2)-1$ holds true for all $x\in R$

I subbed the value of x as zero an obtained $b^2=cos(b^2)-1$ which gives me the value of b as zero,Now I have:
$a(\cos x-1)=cos(ax)-1$

By observation like last time I get a=1, Is (1,0) the only possible pair?

Is there a more rigorous method to solve this question? I guessed my way through it and it's bugging me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $0 \le b^2 = \cos(b^2)-1 \le 1-1$ we see that $b^2 = 0$. Hence $b=0$.

Now we have $a(\cos x-1) = \cos (ax)-1$.

Substituting $x=2\pi$, we have $0=\cos (2\pi a)-1$. $\cos (2\pi a)=1$ implies that $a \in \mathbb Z$.

Substituting $x=\pi$, we have $-2a = \cos (a\pi)-1 = (-1)^a-1 = 0$ or $-2$. Hence $a=0$ or $1$.

Substituting both values of $a$ into our original equation, we have

$$0 = \cos 0 - 1$$

$$\cos x - 1 = \cos x - 1$$

which are both valid for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a = 0$ doesn't work. For $a \neq 0$, the left hand side has minimum period $2\pi$, while the right hand side has minimum period $2\pi / a$. Hence, $a = 1$ is the only possibility.

You could also look in terms of the ranges of the respective functions. The left hand side has range $[-2a, 0]$ if $ a \ge 0$, or range $[0, -2a]$ if $a < 0$. The right hand side has range $[-2, 0]$. This can only match the left hand side if $a = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand how $a=0$ doesn't work?